# proguard propertie not understood

Tags: android, proguard

I am having a hard time understanding what this is doing in proguard:
Does it avoid obfocusing all protected methods in all public classes?

```
-keep public class * {
   public protected *;
}
```

Please explain or refer to some good explanation

Comment: I had a issue with proguard, after spending hours of digging, adding this solve it. I will be glad to know what it's actually doing also...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These lines keep all public classes, and inside these public classes, all public and all protected fields and methods. This means that it keeps all public API of the input code, which is suitable for processing libraries.

See the ProGuard manual > Examples > [A typical library](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#library).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! If I may ask, Isn't that too drastic? Is this a common use in proguard in Android apps?

Comment: You should only use this configuration for processing libraries (as an end-product). It is indeed far too drastic for processing applications, since it keeps many classes/fields/methods from being obfuscated.